# Using "WHEN OTHERS"

Tags: oracle

I've got a question about when I can use WHEN OTHERS clause in EXCEPTION block and not make my code bugged. As I understand it's highly recommended to avoid this practice whenever possible. Here is my case:
I've got a script which loops through the cursor and inserts some data from the cursor into the table. 
Now, in this loop I'm using a function which raises exception if I'm trying to insert incorrect data. So, when the loop hits the record which is incorrect loop is breaking and script execution stops. What I need to do is note that data can't be inserted and go to the next record from cursor. To do that, I've got exception block in the loop which catches exception in WHEN OTHERS, gives a message through DBMS_output.put_line and goes to the next record.
Is that a good way to do this? If not, how should it be done?
Thank you for any advice.

Comment: It's not `WHEN OTHERS` that's bad, it's using it without re-raising the exception that's highly unrecommended. Certainly just sending the error message to serverout is not a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using DBMS_OUTPUT for error handling is almost never a good idea. Here are some suggestions
(all of them use some kind of table structure to store the "invalid" rows):

1. instead of writing an output, store the record in a PL/SQL table
2. replace your loop with FORALL .. SAVE EXCEPTIONS
3. use plain SQL INSERT, combined with an error table for the erroneous rows (use [dbms_errlog](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_errlog.htm) to create the error table)

Personally, I'd go for 3) if your function can be called from SQL.

Comment: +1: Yes, the evil of WHEN OTHERS really arises when it is used to hide errors completely. If the error is being logged then I'd regard that as legitimate -- it can even be logged in a call to an autonomous transaction and then re-raised.

Answer (score 0):

Just because something is not recommended, it doesn't mean you can't use it when it's appropriate. If this fits your requirements and it isn't too slow then don't worry about it. You will probably spend three times as long creating a marginally more elegant solution, time you can probably use on something (or someone) else.

Answer (score 0):

The last line in any WHEN OTHERS handler should be RAISE;

WHEN OTHERS should be reserved for unexpected behavior and it should crash your program.  It should never be used as part of routine processing logic.
The correct approach to this is to determine what error the function is returning.  Then your calling program needs to explicitly handle that/those errors.  Your problem is probably actually that the function is doing something goofy with WHEN OTHERS also.

http://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/2017/02/now-not-to-handle-exceptions.html